# Error message using pdflatex on "R's Multiple Sequence Alignment" Package

Tags: errors, rstudio

I am new to using R-studio and the *Multiple Sequence Alignment* package. I am trying to generate a PDF of the outputs from an alignment result, but I keep getting an error message.

I am inputting this code:

```
mySequenceFile <- system.file("examples", "PlasmodiumCSPv2.fasta",     package="msa")
mySequences <- readAAStringSet(mySequenceFile)
mySequences
myFirstAlignment <- msa(mySequences)
msaPrettyPrint(myFirstAlignment, output="pdf", showNames="none",
               showLogo="none", askForOverwrite=FALSE, verbose=FALSE)
```

The command runs, but I get the following errors:

```
! Package TeXshade Error: File `C:/Users/ANDRE_\nobreakspace     {}1/AppData/Local/
Temp/Rtmp6XbL83/seq1fd4687c2e.fasta' not found.

Error in texi2dvi(texfile, quiet = !verbose, pdf = identical(output, "pdf"),      :unable to run 'pdflatex' on 'myFirstAlignment.tex'
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"pdflatex" -interaction=nonstopmode "myFirstAlignment.tex"'     had status 1
```

I have been looking online to trouble without much success. Any suggestions?

Comment: `\nobreakspace{}` was `~` so I guess the system is using the old DOS name for your folder `ANDRE_~1` and then the `~` is being expanded at the wrong time to a non-breaking space command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is coming late, and you may already have solved the problem - but I am posting a reply in case others encounter it.

I am not sure why RStudio throws this error - but i suspect it is how it configures SWeave - which also uses pdfLateX

Anyway, there is an acceptable work-around - which is to first create the tex file using msaPrettyPrint, and then use the texi2pdf function to create a pdf

```
msaPrettyPrint(myFirstAlignment, output="tex", showNames="none",
           showLogo="none", askForOverwrite=FALSE, verbose=FALSE)
texi2pdf("myFirstAlignment.tex", clean=TRUE)
```

Alternatively if you run msaPrettyPrint as a script in plain old R, the single command to output a pdf should work fine.

Regards

Peter